# How to change the class name of a C# project using C# code

Tags: c#

For Example, I have a `goodDay.cs` class; I need to rename it to `badDay.cs` using C# code and have to make sure the project is still working correctly.

How do i do this?

Comment: You will need to edit the `.csproj` file which is Xml in addition to renaming the files.

Comment: @Romoku ...and rename the physical file too ... yes? :)

Comment: `goodDay.cs` is the filename.  If you want to change the name of the class as well, you'll need to edit the file as well (in addition to Romoku's comment above). Is there a reason you want to do it this way vs doing it through Visual Studio?  If you change the actual name of the class (not just the file) you'll have to change all references in the project to that class as well - that's an awful lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
string solutionFolder = @"C:\Projects\WpfApplication10\WpfApplication10";
string CSName = "Goodday.cs";
string newCSName = "BadDay.cs";
string projectFile = "WpfApplication10.csproj";

File.Move(System.IO.Path.Combine(solutionFolder, CSName), System.IO.Path.Combine(solutionFolder, newCSName));
File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(solutionFolder, projectFile),File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(solutionFolder, projectFile)).Replace(CSName,newCSName));
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to write a refactoring tool. This is extremely difficult, and involves implementing a large amount of the C Sharp compiler.

Luckily Microsoft has recently opened up their compiler (and rewritten it in .net). The [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) project is currently in CTP and will allow you use figure out what the C# is doing, and will help you with refactoring in code (companies like JetBrains had to write their own C# parser from scratch).

Here is a [sample I found from a blog post](http://lessisthenewmore.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/roslyn-sample-rename-items-in-a-solution/)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Roslyn.Services;
using Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp;

namespace RoslynSample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    RefactorSolution(@"C:\Src\MyApp.Full.sln", "ExternalClient", "ExternalCustomer");

    Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void RefactorSolution(string solutionPath, string fileNameFilter, string replacement)
    {
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(solutionPath);

    var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;

    if (solution != null)
    {
        foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
        {
        var documentsToProcess = project.Documents.Where(d => d.DisplayName.Contains(fileNameFilter));

        foreach (var document in documentsToProcess)
        {
            var targetItemSpec = Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(document.Id.FileName),
            document.DisplayName.Replace(fileNameFilter, replacement));

            builder.AppendFormat(@"tf.exe rename ""{0}"" ""{1}""{2}", document.Id.FileName, targetItemSpec, Environment.NewLine);
        }
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllText("rename.cmd", builder.ToString());
    }
}
}
```